# Comparison problems [.equals()] in java

Tags: java, comparison

I am trying to determine whether a string contains a positive int or not. My code is:

```
public void isInt(String str) throws NotIntException{
    String integer=str.replaceAll("\\d","");
    System.out.println(integer);
    if (!integer.equals("")){
        throw new NotIntException("Wrong data type-check fields where an integer"+
        " should be.");
    }//end if
    if (integer.equals("-")){
        System.out.println(integer);
        throw new NotIntException("Error-Can't have a negative count.");
    }//end if
}//end method
```

I am testing this with a string "-1", which should, after the replaceAll(), become "-". This should enter both if-statements. But it only enters the first. I tried it with the == comparison too, just in case, but it didn't work either. What's odd to me is that whether I look to fulfill the second if-statement's condition or to fulfill its negation [i.e., !integer.equals("-")], the program still doesn't enter the if....

Thanks, usually my comparison issues are just me missing something basic, but I really don't see anything here...

Comment: Can't you just `Integer.parseInt()` and see if it throws or is negative?

Comment: If it enters the first and throws an exception... how is it ever supposed to enter the second?  confused

Comment: @Esailija sry, I overread your comment, had the same approach, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are throwing an Exception in your first if, so, your 2nd if will not even be tested.

```
if (!integer.equals("")){
    throw new NotIntException("Wrong data type-check fields where an integer"+
    " should be.");
}

if (integer.equals("-")){
    System.out.println(integer);
    throw new NotIntException("Error-Can't have a negative count.");
}
```

If your code enters the first `if`, it will not execute further.

---

But, why are you using this approach for your problem.

You can easily use `Integer.parseInt` to check for valid `integer`. And then if it is valid, then test whether its `less than 0`. It would be far easier and readable.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
public static boolean isPositiveInt(String str) {
    try {
       int number = Integer.parseInt(str.trim());
       return number >= 0;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
       return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply read an int from a String, use Integer.parseInt(), although that would only work if you want to see if a string "is" an int, not contains one.

You could use a combination of Integer.parseInt() and a loop strategy to see if it contains an int fairly easily though, then just check if that is positive or not.

Answer (score 0):

You approach is too complicated. I would keep it simple:

```
if (integer.startsWith("-")) {
    // it's a negative number
}

if (!integer.matches("^\\d+$")) {
    // it's not all-numbers
}
```

and forget the call to `replaceAll()`